# Kibana :: How to make a Yes/No Vertical Bar Chart?? (Horizontal Population Pyramid)

Tags: data-visualization, kibana

Does anyone know how to make a Horizontal Population Pyramid like the one in the header image located in this article? I want Yes to go up vertically and No to go down vertically.. https://www.elastic.co/blog/from-tableau-to-elastic-how-samtec-streamlined-business-intelligence-and-analytics

[image]

Was this created with vega or classical kibana visualizations?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that graph was made with Vega, simply because most likely I would have been asked for help in building it :).  That said, Vega allows you to build things like that, e.g. see [this graph](https://vega.github.io/vega/examples/population-pyramid/).  Also, while I haven't tried it, I suspect that example can be substantially reduced in the size by using a single `rect` mark inside a single `group`, but I wouldn't know for sure until I try to refactor it.